# Check the arguments for all annotated methods at runtime

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, interceptor

How can you perform a check at startup-time on all the usages of an annotation?

For instance, I have this aspect, that is applied to the methods annotated with `@Protect`, that applies some security policy. Across the system, we have methods annotated with `@Protect("valid-operation-1")`, `@Protect("valid-operation-2")` or `@Protect("INVALID-operation")`. As soon as the application starts up, I'd like to check the arguments provided for all these annotations in order to detect such misconfigurations.

In particular, I'll check that we have a bean defined in the Spring application context whose ID matches the argument of the annotation. That means, to protect the method `void drive()`, I'll annotate with `@Protect("drive")`, and expect a bean `protect_drive` to be present in the application context.

You can easily just wait until the method is invoked, then the advice is called, and you check the argument. Then you'll see that `INVALID-operation` is wrongly defined. But this is *too late*.

Is it possible to have this checked for all annotated methods when the application starts?

Comment: This will require you to load all these classes at startup.  Is the effect on startup time acceptable?

Comment: Can you provide some insight into the nature of the "operation" strings?  What control do you have over them?  Could they be constrained, say, to be valid Java names (no dashes, et al)?  Is there a set of them that's valid globally across the system?  Could this set be compiled as an enum - then use enum values in your @Protect?  Etc...

Comment: Ed, I've updated the question with a clarification on the arguments of the annotations. I don't have control over them.

The startup time can take long, it wouldn't be an issue. But you raise an interesting point there. On the other hand, you could access the pointcut expression and do the same search as the AspectJ engine does, which I assume is pretty inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

If the Classes you want to check are Spring Beans, then you can use a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp).

```
public class OnlyAScratchForAnPostProcessor {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;


    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean,
        final String beanName) throws BeansException {

          ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(bean.getClass(), new MethodCallback() {

             @Override
             public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                         IllegalAccessException {

                  String expecedNameFromAnnotation = scanAnnotation(method);
                  if(expecedNameFromAnnotation != null) {
                      if(context.beanByName(expecedNameFromAnnotation) != null) {
                         throw new RuntimeException("illegal configuration");
                      }
                  }         
             }

             String scanAnnotation(Method method){...}

          }, ReflectionUtils.USER_DECLARED_METHODS);        

    }
```